# Back up rented VPS that does not have that option

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, vps, openvz

I'm currently renting a linux VPS from a host that doesn't grant the option to create a backup or snapshot. In my previous experiences with other hosts most of them had the ability to do so.

And for safety I'd like to back up all my configurations and installed programs in case anything should go wrong and being able to deploy my service back asap.

My VPS runs on Ubuntu 14.04 in OpenVZ (SolusVM managed).

What is a good way to backup and, in case needed, restore everything?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `rsync`. You can just rsync to your single backup if your goal is to have a backup if the VPS disappears, but for minimally more hard disk space you can use [rsync hardlinked backups](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/).

You probably need to have a Linux system to backup to, because while rsync exists for Windows I don't think it would work with hard links.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [`tar`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html), baby.

Maybe `rsync` if you want to get fancy.

---

But seriously speaking, there's a host of options that exist for network backups. Many of them are OS-dependent, though. Depending on what you need, the strategy will change.

Do you only change your configurations often? Then you might do better to use a configuration management tool like Puppet or Ansible, and deploy as needed from a local machine. Do yo have data on the instance needing storage of incremental binary changes, like a database? Then you're going to want a solution more advanced.

The point is you're currently asking to back up the filesystem, but what it sounds like you actually need done is primarily to keep the set of files and configurations used most often in the same state.

If that's the case, then `tar` is still your friend. `rsync` will help you offload that data to another dedicated host.

Otherwise, your VPS should at least offer the ability to clone your instance. If they can't, then seriously— get a better VPS provider, and fast.

Comment: `tar` works once, but it is very inefficient when you want to backup regularly.

Comment: @Law29 everyone's a critic. Does linux `tar` not have a `--diff` option?

Comment: It certainly does! But I don't think using it would simplify things for Sevenzzz or reduce bandwidth for his backups . . .

Comment: +1 for the edit suggesting that Sevenzzz might actually not need to backup the VPS, but deploy the VPS.

Answer (score 0):

My best option would be Attic Backup, free and open source, written in python.

https://attic-backup.org

It can handle out of the box incremental backups and daily/weekly/monthly rotation all with minimum effort and a very small package.

Also it does automatic backup via cron, so you will be ready in 3 minutes.

Tar and rsync it's fine, but as for a simple and automated solution, Attic should be faster to implement

Comment: But how well does it restore?

Comment: Excelent. Also out of the box can move backups via ssh to other box , and also encrypt them. Till now i have found only one drawback that it can only work as root. In a jailed environment or pretty restricted, ita pretty hard to make it work